# AngularJs and Slim Framework with .htaccess

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, slim

I use Angularjs and more precisely ng-view, here is my index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="fr" data-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <base href="/" target="_self" />

</head>
<body>
    <header class="container-fluid" data-ng-include="'/partial/Menu/menu.html'"></header>

    <section class="container-fluid" data-ng-view></section>

</body>
```

Now my index.php with

```
require '/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\App();

/* Routes */

require '/../application/routes.php';

$app->run();
```

I use as platform wampserver and I would make a redirection .htaccess 
to manage url if mydomaine/.... redirection towards index.html but if mydomaine/api/.... redirection towards index.php

I do not know if I use the right method. Here is my .htaccess but which does not work

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^api/ index.php [END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [L]
```

Currently I do not have to redirect my html, my conditions are not to be good.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late, but I was fighting whit this too, and then sun raised and my solution came with it:

- Host your SLIM api in a different DIR or folder, something like /api
- Host your angular app in a different DIR or Folder something like /app

Then modify your .htaccess at root level into something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#prueba 1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/index.html [L]
```

You **MUST** build your angular app, modifying the --base-href in a way that it matches your server directory ("/app")

Then, inside your "/api" folder, make an .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
      RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
      RewriteBase /api/
      RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
      php_value   always_populate_raw_post_data   -1
</IfModule>
```

Optimal solution? Do not know. But it is working right now in production.

I am open to any suggestions. I am not a .htaccess developer.

Answer (score 0):

Working `.htaccess` rules with Slim and Angular

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/. /api/index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```